# Can't install the ffmpeg module

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I'm trying to install ffmpeg-binaries it works perfectly local but when I go to hiroku it starts to say that he can't find the modules.

This is for a Discord bot, running node.js I tried to install with npm other ffmpeg's but only that works without implementing the ffmpeg itself

Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)

```
   > lzma-native@3.0.8 install /tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native
   > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build && node node_modules/rimraf/bin.js build

   node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://node-pre-gyp.addaleax.net/lzma-native/lzma_native-v3.0.8-node-v67-linux-x64.tar.gz 
   node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for lzma-native@3.0.8 and node@11.6.0 (node-v67 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
   node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://node-pre-gyp.addaleax.net/lzma-native/lzma_native-v3.0.8-node-v67-linux-x64.tar.gz 
   node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for lzma-native@3.0.8 and node@11.6.0 (node-v67 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
   gyp: Call to 'sh liblzma-config.sh "/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native/build" "/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native/deps/xz-5.2.3.tar.bz2"' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
   gyp ERR! configure error 
   gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:188:13)
   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:254:12)
   gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1031-aws
   gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.8-node-v67-linux-x64/lzma_native.node" "--module_name=lzma_native" "--module_path=/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.8-node-v67-linux-x64"
   gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native
   gyp ERR! node -v v11.6.0
   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
   gyp ERR! not ok 
   node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.8-node-v67-linux-x64/lzma_native.node --module_name=lzma_native --module_path=/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.8-node-v67-linux-x64' (1)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:188:13)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1031-aws
   node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
   node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native
   node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v11.6.0
   node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
   node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
   Failed to execute '/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.8-node-v67-linux-x64/lzma_native.node --module_name=lzma_native --module_path=/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.8-node-v67-linux-x64' (1)
   gyp: Call to 'sh liblzma-config.sh "/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native/build" "/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native/deps/xz-5.2.3.tar.bz2"' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
   gyp ERR! configure error 
   gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:188:13)
   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:254:12)
   gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1031-aws
   gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.8-node-v67-linux-x64/lzma_native.node" "--module_name=lzma_native" "--module_path=/tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.8-node-v67-linux-x64"
   gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_681c54b9c6315cfb1c9672e8da7d4803/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native
   gyp ERR! node -v v11.6.0
   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
   gyp ERR! not ok 
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 1
   npm ERR! lzma-native@3.0.8 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build && node node_modules/rimraf/bin.js build`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Failed at the lzma-native@3.0.8 install script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.85YKx/_logs/2019-01-13T20_55_48_321Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the infamous `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build` (responsible for the fail of your deployment). On the Github of `mapbox/node-pre-gyp`, there are [70 different issues](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+node-pre-gyp+install+--fallback-to-build) referencing errors on this exact command! `node-pre-gyp` is a *very buggy* package to install - especially when it comes to cross-OS behavior - so some solutions might work for you, some won't.

---

In [this issue](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues/381#issuecomment-440724633), Nicolas Noble (author of the GRPC package) pointed out that the issue arose from incompatible versions of NodeJS and GRPC. Check that your local version of NodeJS is compatible with the one that is running on Heroku, else check [Heroku's guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version) on specifying a Node version.

---

In [this issue](https://github.com/addaleax/lzma-native/issues/70), user takase1121 had a very similar error log as you, looking like:

```
> lzma-native@4.0.2 install [...]Node.js [...]node_modules/lzma-native
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build && rimraf build

[...]
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): [...]
[...]
```

People mentionned also ffmpeg libraries in this issue, which is still open however.

---

Finally in [this issue](https://github.com/addaleax/lzma-native/issues/45), user OceanHorn made the (almost) exact same command as you work fine!

```
> lzma-native@3.0.2 install /Users/OceanHorn/SourceTree/mmms/node_modules/lzma-native
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build && node node_modules/rimraf/bin.js build

[lzma-native] Success [...]
```

One tiny difference: the version of `lzma-native` is 3.0.2, not like your 3.0.8 - using this version of `lzma-native` might solve your problem. Since it is only a patch version difference, you should be able to use version 3.0.2 without any change in your code.

Comment: I just rolled back the version of npm and node from latest to npm:6.4.1 and node:10.15.0 and it worked

Comment: Wow didn't even expected it!  Don't forget to add your solution to Github issues, you'll be thanked again (oh... and send it to [this desperate guy](https://devrant.com/rants/1392967/quick-disclaimer-it-is-easily-googlable-but-no-matter-where-i-search-i-cant-find) too ^^ )